# MySQL group by - union all

Tags: mysql, union-all

I have this query for a report:

```
select @t := '' as 'Clave', @tf:='Inventario Físico' as 'Descripción', @t:= '' as 'Cantidad', @t:= '' as 'Precio Unitario' union all 
select @t:= '', @t:= '', @t:= '', @t:= '' union all 
(select cla, des, can, CAST(pl1*can as Decimal(10,2)) from inventario order by cla) union all 
select @t:= '', @t:='', @tnde := 'Número de Elementos: ', count(*) from inventario union all 
select @t:= '', @t:= '', @tne:= 'Suma total: $', sum(ppu) from inventario;
```

I need an "order by" for the 3rd query.

```
select cla, des, can, CAST(pl1*can as Decimal(10,2)) from inventario order by cla
```

By itself, that line of code works perfectly, but, when it's between the unions, all the info it is not ordered. How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`union all` does *not* guarantee that the data is in the order specified by the subqueries.  You need to do an explicit `order by` to get that result.

This approach adds an ordering column to keep the groups together.  The final `order by` clause first orders by `ordering` and then by the column used for ordering the third subquery:

```
(select @t := '' as Clave, @tf:='Inventario Físico' as Descripción,
        @t:= '' as "Cantida", @t:= '' as "Precio Unitario", 0 as ordering
) union all 
(select @t:= '', @t:= '', @t:= '', @t:= '', 1 as ordering) union all 
(select cla, des, can, CAST(pl1*can as Decimal(10,2)), 2 from inventario) union all 
(select @t:= '', @t:='', @tnde := 'Número de Elementos: ', count(*), 3 from inventario) union all 
(select @t:= '', @t:= '', @tne:= 'Suma total: $', sum(ppu), 4 from inventario)
order by ordering, clave;
```

I also changed the single quotes on the column aliases to double quotes.  I think it is good practice to only use single quotes for string constants.